# To connect to my server I'm forced to use iptables -F

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, firewall

To understand better please look this short [video](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/hl/iptablesconflicts.htm)

I can not solve a problem about a problem of dialogue between iptables and *security group* of EC2

The only way to connect to server using my elastic public is IP 35.156.xx.xx:27015 seems to set on EC2 this rule:

```
Custom UDP Rule UDP 27015 0.0.0.0/0
```

BUT this is not enough because I have to use this command from terminal to unlock connection

```
iptables -F
```

In one picture I set this configuration
http://  i.imgur.com/X12Iq9X.png

But what is sense to clear all rules temporally ? Why flush all chains ? Is not dangerous ?

These rules from terminal are no effects

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
```

My relevant data is this - I copy on pastebin because it is little too long
Link: http://pastebin.com/bmxcF2kV

Comment: Your question makes little to no sense to me, given I'm not watching a video to help you. Take a step back, describe the big picture in a way someone other than you can understand it. IPTables and your security groups are independent and do not interact.

Comment: Look this http://i.imgur.com/X12Iq9X.png

Comment: My problem is simply - to connect to server I have to use `iptables -F` but I don't understand why I need to clear all firewall rules to make this

Comment: Solved, thanks - problem it was wrong letter, I was used `-A` insted of `-I`. No amazon problem, I ask mercy

Comment: @labteh not a wrong letter, in fact `iptables -A` appends rules **at the end of the ruleset** whereas `iptables -I` inserts the rule **at a specific position** in the ruleset. That's why your ruleset wasn't filled with desired configuration. Wish you good luck.

Comment: @Farax  I see now, thanks - wrong order of rules - ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **insert** instead of **append** in iptables rule to allow specific port.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
```

Also dont forget to save iptables after apply this rule.

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```